# opening a gnome terminal via python doesn't seem to work when opening a specific directory

Tags: python, subprocess, gnome-terminal

If I run the following from a gnome terminal:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="/home/users"
```

I get a new shell in the '/home/users' directory.

If I run the following in python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--working-directory="/home/users"'])
```

I get a shell opened in my home directory - not in '/home/users'?

Answer (score 1):

In my case when i just remove `""` from argument it's seems to work:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '--working-directory=/home/test'])
```

Also `/home/test` exist in my case.

Comment: Indeed, shell quoting is wrong when you don't have `shell=True` (which is a good thing, in the vast majority of cases) but slightly surprising if you don't understand what the shell does.

Comment: when i put `shell=true` and also i use apostrophes in path then i still get bed result

Comment: Don't do that then.  `shell=True` is evil, *especially* if you don't have a firm grasp of what exactly it does.  (But basically, you need to convert the list of strings back to a single string in order for it to work.)

Comment: ok thanks, i might misunderstand you, i thought that i made something wrong.